# Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab Priority Column

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

The Chrome Developer Tools Network Tab records page assets loading.

I am trying to understand the following regarding the priority column:

1. The factors that determine how priority is assigned to an asset?
2. Can the priority be changed or assigned via the code?

I have looked through the following documentation and not find any reference to the priority column.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading

Answer (score 4):

[Critical Request Chains](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/critical-request-chains) article mentions [Chrome Resource Priorities and Scheduling](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCDuq9H1ih9iNjgzyAL0gpwNFiEP4TZS-YLRp_RuMlc) design-doc for non-SPDY/HTTP/2 connections. These are defined in the browser core, there's no user-level API to control it directly AFAIK.

Chrome 45 and older:

[image]

Chrome 46 and newer work-in-progress:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The priority dimension was added in the new HTTP/2 protocol. It's a hint given by the browser to the server that the server may or may not follow. You as a webdev can't change the priorities set by the browser.

More information: https://speakerdeck.com/summerwind/2-prioritization